# Question about partial application in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have a question about OCaml:
Assume the following function declarations:

```
let secret x y =
   let secret' x y z = x + y - z in 
      let z = if x mod 2 = 0 then y else x - y
    in secret' x z ;;
```

```
print_int (secret 3 2 (-5));;
```

The output will be 9.

Why is the result 9?

Is this the way its calculations are performed?

```
let secret 3 2 =
   let secret' 3 2 z = 3 + 2 - z in 
      let z = if 3 mod 2 = 0 then 2 else 3 - 2
    in secret' 3 1
```

Why doesn't it stop at secret' 3 1 but instead comes up with the result 9?  Computes it  secret' 3 1 (-5) = 3 + 1 -(-5) ? Why?

Comment: Note: `secret 3 2 (-5)` is equivalent to `secret 3 2 ~-5` if you want to cut some parentheses out of your diet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's fix the indentation, as it's quite misleading right now.

```
let secret x y =
   let secret' x y z = x + y - z in 
   let z = if x mod 2 = 0 then y else x - y in
   secret' x z ;;
```

Same function, but doesn't imply that the local `z` is related to the `secret'` function. Second, let's remove some of the variable shadowing, because you're calling `secret'` with a derived `y` (which you call `z` in another place but which is different from `z` in `secret'`), so for the sake of clarity, let's rename those variables.

```
let secret x y =
   let secret' a b c = a + b - c in 
   let z = if x mod 2 = 0 then y else x - y in
   secret' x z ;;
```

Now we make the call

```
secret 3 2 (-5)
```

We have a definition for `secret x y`. So we can forget about the third argument for now and just call this function.

```
(secret 3 2) (-5)
```

Replace with definition.

```
((let secret' a b c = a + b - c in let z = if x mod 2 = 0 then y else x - y in secret' x z) 3 2) (-5)
```

Substitute `3` for `x` and `2` for `y`.

```
(let secret' a b c = a + b - c in let z = if 3 mod 2 = 0 then 2 else 3 - 2 in secret' 3 z) (-5)
```

Simplify `z`, since we know its value.

```
(let secret' a b c = a + b - c in secret' 3 1) (-5)
```

Now we can partially apply `secret'`. We don't have a value for `c` yet (we do in the outer expression, but we're not looking there right now). The above is equivalent to

```
(let secret' a b = fun c -> a + b - c in secret' 3 1) (-5)
```

Oh look! Suddenly the function takes two arguments. And we have two arguments. Let's apply it. Substitute `3` for `a` and `1` for `b`.

```
(fun c -> 3 + 1 - c) (-5)
```

Hey, look! A function of one argument being applied to one argument. Substitute `-5` for `c`.

```
3 + 1 - (-5)
```

and simplify the arithmetic

```
9
```

Answer (score 1):

Silvio Mayolo has correctly identified the issue with variable shadowing. It's important for OCaml newcomers to also realize that despite appearances, there are no functions which take more than one argument. Every function takes one argument and returns some other value. That other value may be another function.

Splitting `secret'` out rather than having it locally defined to have one less level of nesting confusing things:

```
let secret' x y z = x + y - z

let secret x y =
  let z = if x mod 2 = 0 then y else x - y in 
  secret' x z
```

Now, expressing these as functions which take a single argument and return other functions:

```
let secret' =
  fun x -> 
    fun y -> 
      fun z -> x + y - z

let secret =
  fun x -> 
    fun y -> 
      let z = if x mod 2 = 0 then y else x - y in
      secret' x z
```

When you call `secret 3 2 ~-5` you're effectively calling `((secret 3) 2) ~-5)`. Calling `secret 3` yields:

```
fun y -> 
  let z = if 3 mod 2 = 0 then y else 3 - y in
  secret' 3 z
```

Calling that function with an argument of `2` gets you:

```
let z = if 3 mod 2 = 0 then 2 else 3 - 2 in
secret' 3 z
```

Which we can reduce to:

```
secret' 3 (3 - 2)
```

Or:

```
secret' 3 1
```

Now, calling `secret' 3` yields:

```
fun y -> 
  fun z -> 3 + y - z
```

Calling that function with argument `1` yields:

```
fun z -> 3 + 1 - z
```

And then as Silvio pointed out we call that with `-5`.

```
3 + 1 - ~-5
```

And get `9`.